PostgreSQL: Clone rows but replace one column
Image I have the following table: (in reality there are more columns)
 user_id | product_id
---------|------------
        1|           1
        1|           2
        1|           3
        2|           2
        2|           3

Basically, I need to copy all rows with user_id = 1 but change it to user_id = 3:
 user_id | product_id
---------|------------
        1|           1
        1|           2
        1|           3
        2|           2
        2|           3
        3|           1
        3|           2
        3|           3


@JonasMetzler I want to insert them into the same table

create table clone_test( user_id integer, product_id integer);

insert into clone_test values (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,2), (2,3);

insert into clone_test (select 3, product_id from clone_test where user_id =1);

select * from clone_test ;
 user_id | product_id 
---------+------------
       1 |          1
       1 |          2
       1 |          3
       2 |          2
       2 |          3
       3 |          1
       3 |          2
       3 |          3



Is there any way to do it without manually listing all other columns?

I answered the question you asked. If there is more to the story then you need to change the question to reflect what you are really wanting. Bottom line if you want to add new data to the table it has to come from somewhere.

@xaxa No simple way. Don't be lazy, write out the column names. You could maybe avoid this using a temp table or fetchting the list of columns from a information table, but it's ugly.

@xaxa "Is there any way to do it without manually listing all other columns?" -- No. SQL requires you to type the specific columns you want to use; the only exception is the wildcard * that represents all the columns of a table, or all the columns of the joined tables.


copy all rows with user_id = 1 but change it to user_id = 3:

As already demonstrated by @Adrian Klaver, that's a simple query with a constant in place of the user_id:
demo at db<>fiddle
insert into your_table 
select 3 as user_id, product_id 
from your_table
where user_id=1;


Is there any way to do it without manually listing all other columns?

There is, but

modern IDEs can typically be configured to identify your db schema, so they can add those columns on their own, without you having to type all of them out
dynamic SQL can be used to query your information_schema to add those columns into your query, but that's pretty ugly
both dynamic SQL and the jsonb trick are quite costly and ugly, so it's better to make sure benefits of this justify that price

You can use auto-mapping Postgres does when converting records to and from jsonb:
insert into clone_test 
select (jsonb_populate_record( null::clone_test
                              ,jsonb_set(to_jsonb(clone_test) 
                                         ,'{user_id}'
                                         ,to_jsonb(3))
                             )
       ).*
from clone_test
where user_id=1;


to_jsonb() grabs entire rows from the table and maps them to jsonb.
In each, jsonb_set() changes user_id to a 3.
jsonb_populate_record maps the updated jsonb back to a clone_test record.
().* unpacks the record, separating the columns.

Doing all that just to avoid having to tab through auto-completion, type out or copy the column list, is an overkill.
